# Get results if data exists in BOTH tables

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an SQL search written in VBA (Excel) that works and finds test data from  table(test1) OR table(test2)

However is it possible to write it so that it reports back only if the person has data in BOTH tables, i.e. data from table(test1) **AND** table(test2)

here is my current search that only works as OR:

```
Worksheets.ADD(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "TEST"
Sheets("TEST").Select
Range("A1").Select

Dim TEST As String
    TEST = "SELECT DISTINCT s.master_id, s.eventdate, s.code " _
        & "FROM test1 s INNER JOIN person p ON s.master_id=p.entity_id AND p.audit=1 " _
        & "WHERE s.audit=1  " _
        & "UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT h.master_id, h.eventdate, h.code " _
        & "FROM test2 h INNER JOIN person p ON h.master_id=p.entity_id AND p.audit=1 " _
        & "WHERE h.audit=1 " _
        & "ORDER BY master_id "

Set rs = conn.Execute(TEST)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.ADD(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Refresh
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this would help

```
TEST = "SELECT DISTINCT s.master_id, s.eventdate, s.code " _
    & "FROM test1 s INNER JOIN person p ON s.master_id=p.entity_id AND p.audit=1 " _
    & "WHERE s.audit=1 and exists (select 1 from test2 h1 where s.master_id = h1.master_id) " _
    & "UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT h.master_id, h.eventdate, h.code " _
    & "FROM test2 h INNER JOIN person p ON h.master_id=p.entity_id AND p.audit=1 " _
    & "WHERE h.audit=1 and exists (select 1 from test1 s1 where s1.master_id = h.master_id)" _
    & "ORDER BY master_id "
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace that SQL with this one :

```
SELECT P.entity_id, s.eventdate eventdate_1, s.code code_1, h.eventdate eventdate_2, h.code code_2
FROM PERSON P
     INNER JOIN TEST1 S ON S.master_id = P.entity_id AND S.audit = 1
     INNER JOIN TEST2 H ON H.master_id = P.entity_id AND H.audit = 1
WHERE P.audit = 1
ORDER BY P.entity_id
```

It shows data on Test1 and Test2 for Persons on both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the JOIN SYNTAX.

In your case INNER JOIN displays only the person which has COMMON DATA in BOTH Tables. ( The equivalent of intersection in mathematics )